# Can I send an RMPV `Value` back to rmp_serde for deserialization?

Tags: rust, serde, msgpack

I have a large, somewhat complicated data structure that I can serialize and deserialize with `serde` and `rmp-serde`, but I find that deserialization is quite slow. I think this is because my data structure includes two rather large HashMaps. I don't know how efficiently `rmp_serde::from_slice` can create the HashMap -- will it initialize using `.with_capacity` or does it just create a HashMap and insert one-by-one? And besides, I've found that AHashMap gives me considerable performance improvements elsewhere, so I'm trying to avoid using the default HashMap.

I want to try deserializing with [`rmpv::decode::value::read_value`](https://docs.rs/rmpv/0.4.7/rmpv/decode/value/fn.read_value.html), but I'd like to leave most of the deserialization to rmp_serde and only implement some deserialization myself given some [`Value`](https://docs.rs/rmpv/0.4.7/rmpv/enum.Value.html). Is there a way to choose which pieces I manually deserialize?

Conceptually, what I'd like to do is something like:

```rust
let v = rmp::decode::read_value(&mut reader).unwrap();   // get some Value
let arr : &Vec<Value> = v.as_array().unwrap();           // v is known to be an array
let first_value : MyType = deserialize_manually(arr[0]); // I'll convert the Value myself
let second_value : AnotherType = arr[1].into();          // allow rmpv to convert Value for me
```

I'm currently using rmp-serde 0.14 and rmpv 0.4.7. [The rmp_serde changelog](https://github.com/3Hren/msgpack-rust/blob/master/rmp-serde/CHANGELOG.md) and [rmp_serde release page](https://github.com/3Hren/msgpack-rust/releases) don't provide granular details on what's changed, so I have no reason yet to believe upgrading to the current (v0.15.4 as of writing this question) will provide any new capabilities.

I know that serde provides a [`deserialize_with` attribute](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#deserialize_with). Maybe this is the appropriate route to go, so alternately, my question would be: how can I use `deserialize_with` to deserialize a specific MsgPack field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using `deserialize-with`. First, I had to annotate my struct:

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    some_number: i32,
    #[serde(deserialize_with="de_first_value")]
    first_value : HashMap<i32, String>, // T1 & T2 don't matter
    second_value : AnotherType,
}
```

Then I create this function that will drive deserialization. Because I'm deserializing a `HashMap`, I follow serde's [Implement Deserialize for a custom map type](https://serde.rs/deserialize-map.html):

```rust
fn de_first_value<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<HashMap<i32, String>, D::Error>
where
    D: serde::de::Deserializer<'de>,
{
    deserializer.deserialize_byte_buf(MyHmVisitor)
}
```

Then I define `MyHmVisitor` and implement [the Visitor trait](https://serde.rs/impl-deserialize.html). For deserializing a HashMap, I have to implement the `visit_map` function; I assume that I could do a similar deserialization for other types in this way by implementing [the default provided methods](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/de/trait.Visitor.html#provided-methods) (which all fail with a type error unless overridden):

```rust
struct MyHmVisitor;

impl<'de> serde::de::Visitor<'de> for MyHmVisitor {
    type Value = HashMap<i32, String>;

    /// "This is used in error messages. The message should complete the sentence
    /// 'This Visitor expects to receive ...'"
    /// https://docs.serde.rs/src/serde/de/mod.rs.html#1270
    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(formatter, "a HashMap<i32, String>")
    }

    fn visit_map<A>(self, mut map: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
    where
        A: serde::de::MapAccess<'de>,
    {
        // extract the size hint from the serialized map. If it doesn't exist, default to 0
        let capacity = map.size_hint().unwrap_or(0);

        let mut hm = HashMap::with_capacity(capacity);

        while let Some((k, v)) = map.next_entry()? {
            hm.insert(k,v);
        }

        hm
    }
}
```